# Java - extract JSON values from string using multi regex

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to use [this multi regex java library](https://github.com/fulmicoton/multiregexp) to extract JSON field value from a string.

My JSON look like this:

```
{
  "field1": "something",
  "field2": 13
  "field3": "some"
}
```

I have created a regex pattern to fit each field, and it is working with Java Regex Pattern by simply doing something like this for each pattern:

```
Matcher matcher = patternToSearch.matcher(receiveData);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            return matcher.group(1);
        }
```

I decided to try and improve the code and use multi regex so instead of scanning the string 3 times, it will scan it only one time and extract all needed values.

So I came up with something like this:

```
String[] patterns = new String[]{
                    "\"field1\":\\s*\"(.*?)\"",
                    "\"field2\":\\s*(\\d+)(\\.\\d)?",
                    "\"field3\":\\s*\"(.*?)\"",
            };
            this.matcher = MultiPattern.of(patterns).matcher();
```

the `matcher` has only one method - `match` - used like this:

```
int[] match = this.matcher.match(jsonStringToScan);
```

so I ended up with a list of integers, but I have no idea how to get the json values from these strings and how those integers are helping me. The multi regex `matcher` does not support the `group` method I used before to get the value.

Any idea of how I can extract multiple json values from string using multi regex? (Scanning string only once)

Comment: Why you are not using a Json library?

Comment: Performance. JSON is much slower when you have thousands of strings to parse every second. JSON reads the whole string, regex stops when he found the patterns.

Comment: The fact that this library lacks any documentation whatsoever makes me somewhat sceptical of its quality. I’m *guessing* the return value of the `match` method is an array of the first match positions corresponding to the match start. If so you could re-match starting at those positions to find the end of the match, and then run a JSON parser on the corresponding substring. Either way, you won’t be able to do this purely with a single pass with that library.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on [github page from your link](https://github.com/fulmicoton/multiregexp) `match` returnes indexes of patterns matched. Another point from this page:

> The library does not handle groups.

Consider matching key as group too. Look at this simple example:

```
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"(field.)\":((?:\".*?\")|(?:\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?))");
    final Matcher m = p.matcher("{\"field3\":\"hi\",\"field2\":100.0,\"field1\":\"hi\"}");
    while (m.find()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) {
            System.out.print(m.group(i) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

It prints:

```
field3 "hi" 
field2 100.0 
field1 "hi"
```

If you want to avoid quotes in value group, you need more complicated logic. I've stopped at:

```
        final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"(field.)\":(?:(?:\"(.*?(?=\"))\")|(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?))");
```

resulting in

```
field3 hi null 
field2 null 100.0 
field1 hi null
```

Comment: My keys are not "field1", "field2", and "field3" - it was an example.  just need to get the values, not the keys, if that makes any difference.

Comment: @TheUnreal You can match any string key you need. If you use groups for keys, you can utilize HashMap or something else with them. It is only needed if keys order is not guaranteed. If keys come always in defined order you can match only values.

Comment: The code you in your example is using java pattern, which is using slower regex algorithm to extract values, I need to use the multi regex lib I showed above and find it using the indexes of the patterns, is it possible ?

Comment: I proposed solution using standard java.util.regex.Pattern with one pattern compiled. I do not know if multiple patterns solution can be better. Probably you can utilize `MultiPatternSearcher.Cursor` mentioned on that lib's page to get start and end indexes of value but then you need to take substring nonetheless so it affects efficiency too.

Comment: The reason I want to use the multi patterns is that it is using DFA while `java.util.regex` is using NFA, which is much much faster. Using the `java.util.regex` is not performance wise in my case.